# Can I gitignore files with a prefix?

Tags: git, gitignore, prefix

I have file **a.css** and **b.css** in the same folder. My framework combines those files in a file called **temp.a12cab4598347b07f0079d.css**
This file will be generated wherever there is a css file, so folder matching is no good.
Can I ignore all these files using something like

```
temp.*.css
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to add your mask to .gitignore? it works well.

Comment: reading this answer after almost 2 years of having posted it, I realize that my true lacking area was linux globbing, I didn't know anything about globbing and now that I do it certainly helps with understanding how git ignore files are structured, for anyone in my situation, maybe someone that uses windows for programming, lookup this term, globbing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It will work as expected.

Also, if you need to do this recursively in any subdirectory

```
**/temp.*.css
```

Comment: I was not very familiar with globbing in general, it seems that git patterns look a lot like linux console globbing wildcards, am I right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that works just fine.  The wildcard character in the middle of your string works well.

A great reference for gitignore patterns, matching, and rules is [the official documentation on gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).